# Running Snort as Service

Tags: snort

I am running snort on windows to sniff single interface. I wanted to sniff two interface with snort and I learned I have fire same command twice for different interface.

Now i want run it as service and i used this command`

> c:\snort\bin\snort.exe /SERVICE /INSTALL -i 1 -l c:\snort\log -c c:\snort\etc\snort.conf

This will create a service for Snort .
So, how to run snort as service for multiple interface ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with Snort on windows, but if you're able to do it, it should work similar to Linux.  You would have to bridge the interfaces ([windows 7 steps](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-network-bridge#1TC=windows-7)) and use the bridge with the -i.  If you bridge your 2 interfaces and then run "snort -W" and see the bridge show up, you should just be able to use that to sniff on both interfaces. I have never tested this though, but in theory it should work.